# group_by() summarise() and weights percentages - R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, data-manipulation

Let's suppose that a company has 3 Bosses and 20 Employees, where each `Employee` has done `n_Projects` with an overall `Performance` in percentage:

```
> df <- data.frame(Boss = sample(1:3, 20, replace=TRUE),
                  Employee = sample(1:20,20),
                  n_Projects = sample(50:100, 20, replace=TRUE),
                  Performance = round(sample(1:100,20,replace=TRUE)/100,2),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
   Boss Employee n_Projects Performance
1     3        8         79        0.57
2     1        3         59        0.18
3     1       11         76        0.43
4     2        5         85        0.12
5     2        2         75        0.10
6     2        9         66        0.60
7     2       19         85        0.36
8     1       20         79        0.65
9     2       17         79        0.90
10    3       14         77        0.41
11    1        1         78        0.97
12    1        7         72        0.52
13    2        6         62        0.69
14    2       10         53        0.97
15    3       16         91        0.94
16    3        4         98        0.63
17    1       18         63        0.95
18    2       15         90        0.33
19    1       12         80        0.48
20    1       13         97        0.07
```

The CEO asks me to compute the quality of the work for each boss. However, he asks for a specific calculation: Each `Performance` value has to have a weight equal to the `n_Project` value over the total `n_Project` for that boss.

For example, for Boss 1 we have a total of 604 `n_Projects`, where the project 1 has a Performance weight of `0,13` `(78/604 * 0,97 = 0,13)`, project 3 a Performance weight of `0,1` (`59/604 * 0,18 = 0,02`), and so on. The sum of these Performance weights are the Boss performance, that for Boss 1 is `0,52`. So, the final output should be like this:

```
 Boss  total_Projects Performance
    1             604        0.52
    2             340        0.18  #the values for boss 2 are invented
    3             230        0.43  #the values for boss 3 are invented
```

However, I'm still struggling with this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Boss) %>%
  summarise(total_Projects = sum(n_Projects),
            Weight_Project = n_Projects/sum(total_Projects))
```

In addition to this problem, can you give me any feedback about this problem (my code, specifically) or any recommendation to improve data-manipulations skills? (you can see in my profile that I have asked a lot of questions like this, but still I'm not able to solve them on my own)

Comment: As soon as you don't need grouping anymore, adding an `ungroup()` statement may avoid certain obscure error message when your pipe goes on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some more details about what you did and @akrun's answer :

You must have received the following error message :

```
df %>%
  group_by(Boss) %>%
  summarise(total_Projects = sum(n_Projects),
            Weight_Project = n_Projects/sum(total_Projects))

## Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
##  Column `Weight_Project` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 7
```

This tells you that the calculus you made for `Weight_Project` does not yield a unique value for each `Boss`, but 7. `summarise` is there to *summarise* several values into one (by means, sums, etc.). Here you just divide each value of `n_Projects` by `sum(total_Projects)`, but you don't summarise it into a single value.

Assuming that what you had in mind was first calculating the weight for each performance, then combining it with the performance mark to yield the weighted mean performance, you can proceed in two steps :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Boss) %>% 
  mutate(Weight_Performance = n_Projects / sum(n_Projects)) %>% 
  summarise(weighted_mean_performance = sum(Weight_Performance * Performance))
```

The `mutate` statement preserves the number of total rows in `df`, but `sum(n_Projects)` is calculated for each `Boss` value thanks to `group_by`.
Once, for each row, you have a project weight (which depends on the boss), you can calculate the weighted mean — *which is a mean thus a summary value* — with `summarise`.

A more compact way that still lets appear the weighted calculus would be :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Boss) %>% 
  summarise(weighted_mean_performance = sum((n_Projects / sum(n_Projects)) * Performance))

# Reordering to minimise parenthesis, which is @akrun's answer
df %>% 
  group_by(Boss) %>% 
  summarise(weighted_mean_performance = sum(n_Projects * Performance) / sum(n_Projects))
```

Comment: Indeed, that was exactly the error I had. And thanks for the feedback and explanation, it's super clear!.

Answer (score 4):

We can get the `sum` of product of `n_Projects' and 'Performance' and divide by the 'total_projects'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Boss) %>% 
    summarise(total_projects = sum(n_Projects), 
              Weight_Project = sum(n_Projects * Performance)/total_projects)
    # or
    # Weight_Project = n_Projects %*% Performance/total_projects)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Boss total_projects Weight_Project
#  <int>          <int>          <dbl>
#1     1            604          0.518
#2     2            595          0.475
#3     3            345          0.649
```